# The problem of slicing a list with sublists

Tags: python, list, indexing, slice, sublist

I need to make a slice with the number 74 from the list using indexes (this is the condition of my assignment). But I don't understand what I need to write to get it. Please help.

This is my list:

```
L = [[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]], 
    [[21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30], [31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40]], 
    [[41, 42, 43, 44, 45], [46, [47, 48], 49, 50], [51, 52, 53, 54, 55], [56, 57, 58, 59, 60]], 
    [61, 62, 63, [64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71], 72, 73, 74, [75, [76, 77, 78], 79], 80], 
    [81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100]]
```

And if I write `L[3][6]`, I get 74.

But by writing `L[3[6]::]` , I get an error, even though I need a slice starting with the number with that index.

I need to get something like this:

```
[[74, [75, [76, 77, 78], 79], 80], [81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 
87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100]]
```

Comment: `L[3][6::] + L[4::]` - `[6::]` is only valid for a 3rd element, not a slice starting from that element. You need to take a slice of element at index 3 and everything further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @matszwecja says, `L[3][6:]` gives you the part of the first sub-list you want, and `L[4:]` is the rest of the original list; combine them to get the result you want.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you only have that specific data to process, approaching this with indexes and subscripts will make things difficult because you would need to limit the solution to a specific depth of nesting.  In Python, when you end up manipulating a lot of indexes, it is often a sign that you are missing out on a simpler solution based on iteration.

This filtering (not really slicing) could be achieved with a recursive function that drills down nested lists to get to values and only outputs non-empty lists and values meeting the condition:

```
def deepFilter(data,condition=lambda n:n>=74):
    if isinstance(data,list):
        filtered = (deepFilter(value,condition) for value in data)
        return [value for value in filtered if value != []]
    else:
        return data if condition(data) else []
```

output:

```
print(deepFilter(L))

[[74, [75, [76, 77, 78], 79], 80], [81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88,
  89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100]]
```

You could also do it without recursion.  This example does it "in-place" (modifying the original lists) by building a list of all the subLists and then applying the filter in a bottom-up order (keeping only non-empty lists and values meeting the condition):

```
def deepFilter(data,condition=lambda n:n>=74):
    lists = [data]
    lists.extend(value for subList in lists 
                       for value in subList if isinstance(value,list))
    for subList in reversed(lists):
        subList[:] = (value for value in subList
                      if value != [] 
                      and (isinstance(value,list) or condition(value)) )
```

output:

```
deepFilter(L)
print(L)

[[74, [75, [76, 77, 78], 79], 80], [81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88,
  89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100]]
```

or this non-recursive variant that outputs new filtered lists (by making copies as it builds the list of sublists:

```
def deepFilter(data,condition=lambda n:n>=74):
    lists  = [data.copy()]
    for subList in lists:
        subList[:] = (v.copy() if isinstance(v,list) else v for v in subList)
        lists.extend(v for v in subList if isinstance(v,list))
    for subList in reversed(lists):
        subList[:] = (value for value in subList
                      if value != [] 
                      and (isinstance(value,list) or condition(value)) )
    return lists[0]

print(deepFilter(L))

[[74, [75, [76, 77, 78], 79], 80], [81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88,
  89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100]]
```